# How to improve performance of re-rendering components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a new ReactJs developer, I have a question about the re-rendering topic.
I built a small example which is the same idea as my project in order to learn how to optimize the code.
The example consist of one screen, and the screen consist of many components:
Two main components ( OrderInfo, OrderLayout )
OrderLayout -> (Products, Categories)
Products -> (ProductCard)
***The question is***: How I can prevent re-render unnecessary components when I dispatch a function?
Unnecessary re-renders for me in this project like when clicking on any product,
there is no need to re-render again the whole products with the categories
Code:

```
import React from "react"
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core"

const OrderStateContext = React.createContext()
const OrderDispatchContext = React.createContext()

const OrderProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const initialState = {
    products: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    categories: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    selectedItem: "",
  }
  const orderReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE_PRODUCTS":
        return { ...state, products: action.data }
      case "UPDATE_CATEGORIES":
        return { ...state, categories: action.data }
      case "UPDATE_SELECTEDITEM":
        return { ...state, selectedItem: action.data }
      default:
        break
    }
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(orderReducer, initialState)
  const orderDispatchContext = {
    updateSelectedItem: (item) =>
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SELECTEDITEM", data: item }),
  }
  return (
    <OrderStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <OrderDispatchContext.Provider value={orderDispatchContext}>
        {children}
      </OrderDispatchContext.Provider>
    </OrderStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useOrderState = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(OrderStateContext)
  if (context === undefined)
    throw new Error("useOrderState must be used within an OrderProvider")
  return context
}

const useOrderDispatch = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(OrderDispatchContext)
  if (context === undefined)
    throw new Error("useOrderDispatch must be used within an OrderProvider")
  return context
}

function App() {
  console.log("********************* Redner ---- /t APP *********************")
  return (
    <OrderProvider>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <OrderLayout />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <OrderInfo />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </OrderProvider>
  )
}

const Categories = () => {
  console.log("Redner ---- /t Categories")
  const { categories } = useOrderState()
  return (
    <>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <div key={category} style={{ marginLeft: 100 }}>
          {category}
        </div>
      ))}
      <br />
      <br />
    </>
  )
}

const ProductCard = ({ p }) => {
  console.log("Render ---- /t Product Card")
  const { updateSelectedItem } = useOrderDispatch()
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        updateSelectedItem(p)
      }}
    >
      {p}
    </div>
  )
}

const Products = () => {
  console.log("Redner ---- /t Products")
  const { products } = useOrderState()
  return (
    <>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product} style={{ marginLeft: 100, marginBottom: 20 }}>
          <ProductCard p={product} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const OrderLayout = () => {
  console.log("Redner ---- /t Order Layout")
  return (
    <>
      <Categories />
      <Products />
    </>
  )
}

const OrderInfo = () => {
  console.log("Render ---- /t Order Info_____________________")
  const { selectedItem } = useOrderState()
  return <div>{`${selectedItem}.`}</div>
}

export default App
```

After clicking on any product, I don't want to re-render the whole products again with categories and products cards.
The result after each click will be like the following:
Redner ---- /t Categories
Redner ---- /t Products
Render ---- /t Product Card (10 times)
Render ---- /t Order Info_____________________

Thanks

Comment: I tried to wrap each nested component with React.memo, but this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What does "prevent re-render unnecessary components when I dispatch a function?" mean to you? Memoization is the tool used in React, either the `useMemo` or `useCallback` to provide stable references for values and callbacks passed as props, or wrap the children in the `memo` HOC and provide a custom "isEqual" compare function to hint to react that a render may not be necessary. The ***important*** first question however is, "Is there an *actual* performance issue to fix?" React is already fairly optimized out of the box. Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: I mean for unnecessary components like when I click on the product, there is no need to re-render the products again and the categories too, just to show the selected product in the OrderInfo component.

Comment: Also, don't console log in the function body of functional components as these are side-effects and will be invoked any time React renders the component during the "render phase" which ***should not*** be confused with the component being rendered to the DOM during the "commit phase" when you can then do your side effects, like console logging.

Comment: I wrapped each children component with the memo HOC, but sorry I didn't get it how to provide the isEqual function

Comment: [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) Official documentation is your friend. Basically `React.memo(MyComponent, (prevProps, nextProps) => {...})`. Caution though: "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs."

Comment: Ok, thank you @DrewReese, I will try to do it in the proper way.
Because I am new to this topic (React MEMO) I have to understand it very well in order to apply with no problems.

Comment: see also https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders